# Link agains ALSA with CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, alsa, portaudio

I am trying to use PortAudio on Linux, but the compiler complains about undefined references to *ALSA* and *Jack* functions (the exact problem is described at the end of this post). I have setup two CMake projects: Project A and Project B, with one `CMakeLists.txt` per project.

### Project A

Builds an executable and depends on *the_library*:

```
add_subdirectory(${projectB_dir})
add_executable(the_executable ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(the_executable LINK_PUBLIC the_library)
```

### Project B

Builds a library, *the_library*, which depends on `PortAudio`, an `ExternalProject`:

**PortAudio ExternalProject**

```
ExternalProject_Add(project_portaudio
    GIT_REPOSITORY      https://git.assembla.com/portaudio.git
    PREFIX              ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/portaudio
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND   <SOURCE_DIR>/configure
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE     1
    BUILD_COMMAND       make
    INSTALL_COMMAND     ""
    UPDATE_COMMAND      "")

ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio SOURCE_DIR)
set(portaudio_lib_dir "${BINARY_DIR}/lib/.libs")
set(portaudio_inc_dir "${SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_library(portaudio STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET portaudio PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${portaudio_lib_dir}/libportaudio.a")
```

**Native audio APIs** in order for *PortAudio* to work.

```
if(APPLE)
    find_library(CORE_AUDIO_LIBRARY CoreAudio)
    find_library(AUDIO_TOOLBOX_LIBRARY AudioToolbox)
    find_library(AUDIO_UNIT_LIBRARY AudioUnit)
    find_library(CARBON_LIBRARY Carbon)
    SET(NATIVE_AUDIO_LIBS ${CORE_AUDIO_LIBRARY} ${AUDIO_TOOLBOX_LIBRARY} ${AUDIO_UNIT_LIBRARY} ${CARBON_LIBRARY})
elseif(UNIX)
    set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
    find_package(ALSA REQUIRED)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
    SET(NATIVE_AUDIO_LIBS rt ${ALSA_LIBRARIES} jack Threads::Threads)
endif()
```

**The library**

```
add_library(the_library ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
add_dependencies(the_library project_portaudio)

target_include_directories(the_library PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        ${portaudio_inc_dir})

target_link_libraries(the_library ${NATIVE_AUDIO_LIBS} portaudio)
```

### The problem

When I build *Project A* the compiler gives these errors:

```
# A bunch of undefined references to ALSA functions...

[ 93%] Linking CXX executable the_executable
../lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_linux_alsa.o): In function `PaAlsa_LoadLibrary':
/home/tomasito/Development/project-a/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:380: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_open'
/home/tomasito/Development/project-a/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:381: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
/home/tomasito/Development/project-a/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:382: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_nonblock'
/home/tomasito/Development/project-a/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:384: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_prepare'
...


# Followed by a bunch of undefined references to Jack functions...

../lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `GetStreamTime':
/home/tomasito/Development/project-a/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1738: undefined reference to `jack_frame_time'
/home/tomasito/Development/project-a/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1738: undefined reference to `jack_get_sample_rate'
...
```

What am I doing wrong? I am linking ALSA agains my library, *the_library*, but it still complains. I have also tried to link ALSA directly to the executable in project A, but that doesn't make any difference.

PS: These errors I am getting are on Linux. It works like a charm on OSX.

Comment: What is `libB` in the first snippet? How snipped titled `Native audio APIs` is connected with `The library` one? I don't see any include `add_subdirectory()` or similar.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look at the problem! I firstly used `libB` to refer to the library I create in `Project B`, but I thought `the_library` would be a better title. I forgot to change it in the first snippet, though. Thanks! It's updated.

Comment: And all the snippets for `Project B` are in the same `CMakeLists.txt`, so the _Native audio APIs_ snippet is in the same file as the _The library_ titled snippet. I will try to clarify it!

Comment: `Native audio APIs in order for PortAudio to work.` - In other words, `portaudio` needs something from `${NATIVE_AUDIO_LIBS}` libraries, doesn't it? If so, it should be listed **before** `${NATIVE_AUDIO_LIBS}` in `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: Yes, it works! I am still trying to figure out why this library should be listed before its dependencies and not after. But I think I should probably go read something about linking order ;-) Anyway, post an answer and will be happy to accept it :-)